# Asp.net Explicit Localization Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, localization, globalization

I have some problem with the Localization in ASP.net.
I have generated the resources and binding the text property by an variable.
In the source file.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' meta:resourcekey="Label1Resource1"></asp:Label>
```

code behind

```
protected string name;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = "Hello World";
    }
```

The above things are simple but when I run the project.
I got

```
Parser Error
```

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Cannot have more than one binding on property 'Text' on 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'. Ensure that this property is not bound through an implicit expression, for example, using meta:resourcekey.

Source Error:

The above is just an example what I am facing in my project.

Please Help me how can I make localization and binding both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Solution I found is Making the data in between the tags.

like

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  meta:resourcekey="Label1Resource1"><%# Eval("name") %></asp:Label>
```

But this also leads to another problem.

What if I want to access the value of that label inside code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one binding at a time on Page events.
If you want to use both binding then it must besides in different events.

Comment: different Evenets means. Can you eloberate.

Comment: At a time we can not bind particular control with values. so you can bind with different events like Page Load, Button Click ,Page PreRender etc. events

Answer (score 0):

Avoid placing the Text attribute in the markup, as it's already bound to the localized text in the resource file, and just call *Label1.Text = "hello world"*.

Comment: What If the Label is placed inside the GridView Itemtemplate. I dont want that heavy FindControl method in the RowDataBound.